# Custom keybindings without gnome-settings-daemon

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-settings-daemon

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 (Fallback) and I am trying to slim it down, mostly for fun/learning experience.

I killed gnome-settings-daemon because I set up my theming from elsewhere. But now some of my keybindings are lost. I think the windowmanager ones are still working, like Alt-Tab and switch workspace. But my mediakeys to change volume and my custom keybindings are not working anymore.

Is there a different way to save custom keybindings? Do I really need to run settings-manager to setup my keybindings?

Comment: Xbindkeys is nice, but it doesn't work well with function keys.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just figured it out and I use xbindkeys too. I wrote an answer on how I did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! You can use xbindkeys to setup your own keybindings without the need of gnome-settings-daemon. So first:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
```

And then you can generate a default config file:

```
xbindkeys --defaults > ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

To give an example of some stuff I use in my .xbindkeysrc:

```
"amixer -q set Master 2- unmute"
XF86AudioLowerVolume
"amixer -q set Master 2+ unmute"
XF86AudioRaiseVolume
"amixer -q set Master toggle"
XF86AudioMute
"urxvt"
alt+Return
"lxpanelctl run"
alt+r
```

Then run xbindkeys at startup and the custom keybindings work.

Comment: To add to this, if you run `xbindkeys -k` in a terminal, it will give you the xbindkey keysym for any key you press.  This is helpful for finding the name of a key you don't know.